# How to clear Text in dropdown Search programmatically? flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I m new to flutter, i tried to clear the text in the dropdown search, but failed.
I tried :

```
 _PropertyTypeController.text ='';, 
 _PropertyTypeController.clear(),
```

all failed.

```
 return new Container(
        child: DropdownSearch<Type2>(
          //  pop

          searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            controller: _PropertyTypeController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
               
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                onPressed: () {
                  _PropertyTypeController.clear();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          maxHeight: 300,
          dropdownSearchBaseStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
          onFind: (filter) => getTypeSuggestions(
            filter.toString(),
            
          ),

          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            labelText: "choose a Property Type",
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 0, 0),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
          onChanged: print,
          showSearchBox: true,

          popupShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
              topRight: Radius.circular(24),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0));
  }
```

Anyway to clear the text in the _PropertyTypeController (TextEditingController) Programmatically
I want to clear few of the dropdown search's text at once.

dropdown_search: ^2.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your `_PropertyTypeController.clear(),` inside a `setState` to update the UI.

```dart
   setState(() {
      _PropertyTypeController.clear();
  });
```

Please report if that fixes your issue.

Side note: As a convention of the effective dart style guide, variables should start in lower case. So your variable should be called: `_propertyTypeController`
See: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-other-identifiers-using-lowercamelcase

Comment: Thanks for the side note.
It did clear the _propertyTypeController.text but the selected text is not cleared. Meaning to say, once any item Selected, i want to clear it programmatically as there are few dropdowns to clear all at once.
Thanks.
I m using dropdown_search: ^2.0.1.

Comment: Is the `DropdownSearch` from a custom package? It's not built directly into Flutter right?

Comment: I just saw an example of that component with the following setting: `showClearButton: true,`. Have you tried that?

Comment: yup, it can be done clearing text individually. But i need to clear all the 5 dropdowns in 2 separate expandable panels at once.